# Iteration from an arbitrary state of multiple iterators, with: i1 < i2 < i3 ... < in

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I'm looping with multiple iterators, each of which can take values between 0 and 193, and each iterator must also be greater than the previous one (i1 < i2 < i3 ... < in).

For this example, I have 5 iterators; the total number of states to be iterated over is very large (2,174,032,288). Therefore I am processing these states in batches and saving the start and final 'states' from each batch, so I can continue from where it left off.

My following code works. My question is what is the best way of generalising these nested if statements so that it works for any number of ordered iterators, not just 5. Also, is there a better approach to achieve this?

```
rnIndex = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]  # the starting state of indices to iterate from
batchSize = 1000000  # iterate through 1 million index states per batch
batchNumber = 0  # the batch number to start from - 1
batchNumberMax = 10  # run up to and including this batch number
rnLimit = 194  # iterate up to (but not including) for each index
rnComplete = False

while not rnComplete and batchNumber < batchNumberMax:
    batchNumber += 1
    print('\nStart index (included): ' + str(rnIndex))
    rnBatch = []
    for i in range(batchSize):
        if i == batchSize - 1:
            print('Final index (included): ' + str(rnIndex))
        rnBatch.append(rnIndex)  # add each rnIndex to rnBatch
        rnIndex[-1] += 1
        if rnIndex[-1] == rnLimit:
            rnIndex[-2] += 1
            rnIndex[-1] = rnIndex[-2] + 1
            if rnIndex[-2] == rnLimit - 1:
                rnIndex[-3] += 1
                rnIndex[-2] = rnIndex[-3] + 1
                rnIndex[-1] = rnIndex[-2] + 1
                if rnIndex[-3] == rnLimit - 2:
                    rnIndex[-4] += 1
                    rnIndex[-3] = rnIndex[-4] + 1
                    rnIndex[-2] = rnIndex[-3] + 1
                    rnIndex[-1] = rnIndex[-2] + 1
                    if rnIndex[-4] == rnLimit - 3:
                        rnIndex[-5] += 1
                        rnIndex[-4] = rnIndex[-5] + 1
                        rnIndex[-3] = rnIndex[-4] + 1
                        rnIndex[-2] = rnIndex[-3] + 1
                        rnIndex[-1] = rnIndex[-2] + 1
                        if rnIndex[-5] == rnLimit - 4:
                            rnComplete = True
                            break
    print('len(rnBatch) = '+str(len(rnBatch)))  # check the length of rnBatch

print(rnIndex)  # the rnIndex state to resume from
```

out:

```
Start index (included): [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
Final index (included): [0, 1, 94, 99, 133]
len(rnBatch) = 1000000

...

Start index (included): [0, 8, 24, 122, 173]
Final index (included): [0, 9, 23, 54, 90]
len(rnBatch) = 1000000

Start index (included): [0, 9, 23, 54, 91]
Final index (included): [0, 10, 22, 182, 188]
len(rnBatch) = 1000000
[0, 10, 22, 182, 189]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a function that produces the next sequence of indexes from a previous one, and use it to advance through the combinations from any starting point:

```
def nextSeq(maxVal,values):
    for i,v in enumerate(reversed(values),1):
        if v <= maxVal-i:
            return values[:-i]+[values[-i]+k+1 for k in range(i)]
```

output:

```
seq = [0,1,2,3,4]
for _ in range(10):
    print(seq)
    seq = nextSeq(193,seq)

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 5]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 6]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 7]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 8]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 10]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 11]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 12]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 13]
```

The function could also be used to create a generator that can be used in a for-loop (without nesting):

```
def genSeq(maxVal,start):
    seq = list(start)
    while seq:
        yield seq
        seq = nextSeq(maxVal,seq)
```

output:

```
start = [188,189,190,191,192]
for seq in genSeq(193,start):
    print(seq)

[188, 189, 190, 191, 192]
[188, 189, 190, 191, 193]
[188, 189, 190, 192, 193]
[188, 189, 191, 192, 193]
[188, 190, 191, 192, 193]
[189, 190, 191, 192, 193]
```

If you want to jump directly to a specific sequence (Nth sequence), a recursive function can convert an index to a sequence in the same order:

```
from math import factorial as fact
def seqAtIndex(index,maxVal,size):
    if size == 1: return [index]
    value  = base = chunk = 0
    while base+chunk <= index:
        base  += chunk
        value += 1
        chunk  = fact(maxVal+1-value)//fact(size-1)//fact(maxVal+2-value-size)
    return [value-1] \
         + [value+s for s in seqAtIndex(index-base,maxVal-value,size-1)]
```

output:

```
for i in range(10): 
    print(i,seqAtIndex(i,193,5))

0 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
1 [0, 1, 2, 3, 5]
2 [0, 1, 2, 3, 6]
3 [0, 1, 2, 3, 7]
4 [0, 1, 2, 3, 8]
5 [0, 1, 2, 3, 9]
6 [0, 1, 2, 3, 10]
7 [0, 1, 2, 3, 11]
8 [0, 1, 2, 3, 12]
9 [0, 1, 2, 3, 13]

for i in range(2174032280,2174032288):
    print(i,seqAtIndex(i,193,5))

2174032280 [187, 189, 191, 192, 193]
2174032281 [187, 190, 191, 192, 193]
2174032282 [188, 189, 190, 191, 192]
2174032283 [188, 189, 190, 191, 193]
2174032284 [188, 189, 190, 192, 193]
2174032285 [188, 189, 191, 192, 193]
2174032286 [188, 190, 191, 192, 193]
2174032287 [189, 190, 191, 192, 193]
```

*Note that `seqAtIndex` is much slower than `nextSeq` or `genSeq` so you should only use it to find the starting sequence and then use the other functions to advance sequentially*

Comment: This seems like a good solution. I'll try it out when I can, to be sure that I understand it and to check that it works for other lengths of seq. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generator function that yields all possible combination of indices with the constraints you provided that is
each of which can take values between 0 and 193, and each iterator must also be greater than the previous one (i1 < i2 < i3 ... < in).
here is what it looks like:

```
from itertools import combinations

def generate_indices(limit, n):
    # generate all combinations of n numbers
    for combo in combinations(range(limit), n):
        # check if each number is greater than the previous one
        if all(x < y for x, y in zip(combo, combo[1:])):
            yield list(combo)
```

You can use this function in your loop instead of the nested if statements, like this:

```
rnLimit = 194  
n = 5 
batchSize = 1000000  
batchNumber = 0  
batchNumberMax = 20  


index_generator = generate_indices(rnLimit, n)

while batchNumber < batchNumberMax:
    batchNumber += 1
    print('\nStart index (included): ' + str(next(index_generator)))
    rnBatch = []
    for i in range(batchSize):
        try:
            rnIndex = next(index_generator) 
            if i == batchSize - 1:
                print('Final index (included): ' + str(rnIndex))
            rnBatch.append(rnIndex)  
        except StopIteration:
           
            break
    print('len(rnBatch) = '+str(len(rnBatch)))
```

This code should produce the same output as your original code, but it works for any number of ordered iterators.

Comment: This works, but I've gone with Alain's method to increment with a function, which seems simplest

Answer (score 0):

```py
from itertools import product, combinations, islice

batchSize = 3
rnLimit = 7

combs = combinations(range(rnLimit), 5)
while batch := list(islice(combs, 3)):
    print(batch)
```

Output showing the batches, your extra information could be added easily if actually necessary ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TY-xDcIwFER7T_FLWzJVhECRsgEdEyTGwV-y_S37RwhWoUkDLfOwDSEJElddcfd0d3-mKzuK4_gYuN_s368-UwBkm5nIF8CQKDOkTKfBsAZDocPYMlIsGrB4NFaIrmXjjniz0EAlcjxgQJ78TohvoUz2vyhzG89WrjmlYavExaG3MIOgbsBjYbng5YzQUClVC5iUMkaWc1Qts9f1vxcf)):

```
[(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), (0, 1, 2, 3, 5), (0, 1, 2, 3, 6)]
[(0, 1, 2, 4, 5), (0, 1, 2, 4, 6), (0, 1, 2, 5, 6)]
[(0, 1, 3, 4, 5), (0, 1, 3, 4, 6), (0, 1, 3, 5, 6)]
[(0, 1, 4, 5, 6), (0, 2, 3, 4, 5), (0, 2, 3, 4, 6)]
[(0, 2, 3, 5, 6), (0, 2, 4, 5, 6), (0, 3, 4, 5, 6)]
[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (1, 2, 3, 4, 6), (1, 2, 3, 5, 6)]
[(1, 2, 4, 5, 6), (1, 3, 4, 5, 6), (2, 3, 4, 5, 6)]
```